# Running Python 2 and Pip throws error on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

If you've installed Python2 and Python3 with HomeBrew, you might run into this error:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

or this error on VSCode when trying to install

```
Collecting pylint
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pylint
```

The issue seems to be python version conflicts that I have on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
What resolved the issue for me was unlinking Python2 from brew as that was causing version conflicts when running Pip

`brew unlink python@2`

ensure you have updated python3 from homebrew

`brew reinstall python3`

The following could be unsafe, please look for a other help forums on the best practice below:
* Updated your Path to the correct version afterward if you want the warnings to go away

```
WARNING: The script pylint is installed in '/Users/<username>/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
```